# Working with Data Attributes - Build a List & See if One Exists

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I have 2 questions based on the graphic below:

[image]

1. How can I tell if one of the 'data-conversationmessageuserid' data attributes with a specific value exists - say 1000000003? I believe data selectors is what I need and have tried the following but its not working yet:

   ```
   if($('#conversationsInBoxMessagesWrapperDIV')['data-conversationmessageuserid=1000000003']) {
       // do something
   }
   ```
2. How could I get all the 'data-conversationmessageuserid' data attributes into an array and the loop through them? I'm still playing with this code but its far from publishable. Trying to use .map

   .map(function()

thankyou so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
if($('#conversationsInBoxMessagesWrapperDIV [data-conversationmessageuserid=1000000003]').length)
```

or

```
$('#conversationsInBoxMessagesWrapperDIV').find('[data-conversationmessageuserid=1000000003]') //Or children only to look at one level.
```

To get all the data values you could do:

```
   var conversationmessageuserids = $('#conversationsInBoxMessagesWrapperDIV').children().map(function(){
          return $(this).data('conversationmessageuserid');
  }).get();
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery supports data attributes: http://api.jquery.com/data/

So you could do `if($('#conversationsInBoxMessagesWrapperDIV').data('conversationmessageuserid') === 1000000003)`